# RxJava - scope of variables (pure function)

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java2

I have a question. I have RxJava chain and I solve problem of scope of function. Variable calendar is POJO object. Is usage of this variable for constructor of Builder pattern anti-pattern or not?

```
.flatMapSingle(calendar -> {
    Calendar actualDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    return mCalendarResource.getEventsForDay(calendar, actualDay)
    .map(events ->
        new Calendar.Builder(calendar)
        .setEvents(events)
        .build()
    )
})
```

Comment: Where does `calendar` come from? Do you mutate it anywhere after you hand it to RxJava?

Comment: calendar is immutable object

Comment: This is a typical pattern when using `flatMap` to access the original item that generated the inner source later in that inner flow.

Comment: It's a closure so as long as you're not mutating or exposing it publicly it should be perfectly fine.